# Difference between display of html code on website and in QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5

I crawled the html code from a website, which I want to display in a `QTextEdit` form `PyQt5`. The html code is supposed to look like this:

[image: View on website]

When I put the html code into the `QTextEdit`, it looks like this:
[image: View on QTextEdit]

In the enumerations there is an offset in 'QTextEdit', that is not on the website. How do I get rid of this offset so it looks like the website?

The code is on the `QTextEdit` is set with `setHtml`.

The html code is the following:

```
<div class="jurAbsatz">(2) Das Genehmigungserfordernis erstreckt sich auf alle vorgesehenen 
<dl style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
<dt>1.</dt>
<dd style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
<div>Anlagenteile und Verfahrensschritte, die zum Betrieb notwendig sind, und</div>
</dd>
<dt>2.</dt>
<dd style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
<div>Nebeneinrichtungen, die mit den Anlagenteilen und Verfahrensschritten nach Nummer 1 in einem räumlichen und betriebstechnischen Zusammenhang stehen und die von Bedeutung sein können für 
<dl style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
<dt>a)</dt>
<dd style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
<div>das Entstehen schädlicher Umwelteinwirkungen,</div>
</dd>
<dt>b)</dt>
<dd style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
<div>die Vorsorge gegen schädliche Umwelteinwirkungen oder</div>
</dd>
<dt>c)</dt>
<dd style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
<div>das Entstehen sonstiger Gefahren, erheblicher Nachteile oder erheblicher Belästigungen.</div>
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div class="jurAbsatz">(3) Die im Anhang 1 bestimmten Voraussetzungen sind auch erfüllt, wenn mehrere Anlagen derselben Art in einem engen räumlichen und betrieblichen Zusammenhang stehen (gemeinsame Anlage) und zusammen die maßgebenden Leistungsgrenzen oder Anlagengrößen erreichen oder überschreiten werden. Ein enger räumlicher und betrieblicher Zusammenhang ist gegeben, wenn die Anlagen 
<dl style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
<dt>1.</dt>
<dd style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
<div>auf demselben Betriebsgelände liegen,</div>
</dd>
<dt>2.</dt>
<dd style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
<div>mit gemeinsamen Betriebseinrichtungen verbunden sind und</div>
</dd>
<dt>3.</dt>
<dd style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;"><div>einem vergleichbaren technischen Zweck dienen.
</div>
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

Comment: Be aware that, while they have rich text features and can show HTML contents, Qt text widgets only support a [limited subset of HTML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html): they are not web browsers. If you want to display something like you'd see on the web, you should use QWebEngineView.

Comment: Is ist possible to change the html code so QTextEdit resembles the website look? Cause I don‘t want to use QWebEngineView as I need some features of QTextEdit.

Comment: @musicamante even if I display the html code in a QWebEngineView I get the same offset in the enumeration

Comment: @Mazze What features of QTextEdit do you need that aren't available in QWebEngineView?

Comment: @Mazze the HTML you posted clearly needs some CSS. Are those included in the file you're using? Because if they are in external files, they must be included in the HTML if you're just setting the HTML source. Also: 1. if those stylesheets require javascript to properly work, QWebEngineView becomes mandatory; 2. if not, still refer to the limited support for HTML linked above, and remember that that support only respects the CSS 2.1 standard (and only to some extent).

Comment: @Mazze Besides, you can obviously change the HTML. *How* to change it is up to you: that seems quite basic syntax, so if you don't know how to modify it I suggest to look for basic tutorials so that you can understand how those tags work and test the changes until you're satisfied with the result. There's no shortcut for that.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for suggestions. I want to switch back and forth between the text as html for display and the text as non-html for further processing. and this works best with toPlainText() and toHtml(). also the text will be colored based on the non html text. I don't know if this is understandable. But I will take a look at the CSS of the website

Comment: @Mazze the HTML capabilities of QTextDocument (which is the basis of all text based widgets) are just for interoperability. When you call `toHtml()` you will ***never*** get the same HTML code used for `setHtml()`: the latter uses an internal parser that converts the HTML code to a QTextDocument, the former builds a *new* HTML code based on it. Be aware that if you plan to create some sort of WYSIWYG editor that also allows code editing based on the HTML *source*, that's not possible with the Qt rich text engine: that's not its purpose.

Comment: One way to "fix" the html example is to use `ol`/`li` tags instead of `dl`/`dt`/`dd` tags.